# Windows10/Windows8.1: getting Empty error message while running XBootmgr

Tags: wptoolkit

I manually copied WPT folder from a file server onto my Windows10 test machine and ran below XBootmgr command:

**"Xbootmgr -trace shutdown -noPrepReboot -traceFlags BASE+CSWITCH+DRIVERS+POWER -numRuns 1 -resultPath d:\tempetl"**

Note: copied WPT folder at location "C:\WPT" and I have manually created "D:\tempetl"

But it is not running and giving small error pop-up which doesn't contain any error message. Getting same issue on another Windows8.1 machine.

I thought there is some issue with the switches I have used, so I tried simple command:

**"Xbootmgr -trace shutdown -noPrepReboot"**

But faced same issue.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Just a guess...Is there any compatibility issue? Do we need to install different WPT version on Win8.1/Win10?

Answer (score 0):

Manually copy-pasting the WPT folder won't work. You need to install WPT using an MSI file (WPTx64-x86_en-us.msi).

On a Windows PC which has WPT installed on it, you can find this file in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance
>   Toolkit\Redistributables

You can also install WPT as part of Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39982

Also, once you install WPT, you need to restart the computer once before you can start using the WPT commands for xbootmgr and xperf from an elevated command line window.